# Parse php code outputted with print() command

Tags: php, parsing

I am writing a PHP script for my site that takes information from a form, does calculations on it, and returns the result in a new page. What the program itself does isn't the issue here, it's how to format the output. Below is the part of my program that finally writes stuff to a webpage:

```
.... code ....

$output = <<< EOHTML
<?php require_once "../includes/header.htm"; ?>
        <title>$var1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <?php include_once "../includes/banner.htm";
                require_once "../includes/menu.htm"; ?>
            <div class="content">
                <h1>Test</h1>

                <p>Variable 1: $var1</p>
                <p>Variable 2: $var2</p>
                <p>Variable 3: $var3</p>
                <p>Variable 4: $var4</p>
                <p>Variable 5: $var5</p>
                <p>Variable 6: $var6</p>

            </div>
            <?php include_once "../includes/footer.htm" ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
EOHTML;

print($output);
?>
```

However, while the HTML works, it seems to print the PHP parts literally, and the server can't parse it. The various "includes" are for loading parts of my site, including the CSS, so the output is just 6 lines of text on a white background.

Is there a way to either have it output the HTML and PHP (and have both parse properly) or have the PHP output to the same page the form was on?

Comment: PHP will not parse it's output as PHP code. no no. You are completely wrong. You should step back to lession one (if you have a book. otherwise buy one)

Comment: You are taking the wrong approach here. Is the intent here that someone could type in PHP code in a form and have it executed on your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<?php require_once "../includes/header.htm"; ?>
    <title><?php echo $var1; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <?php include_once "../includes/banner.htm";
            require_once "../includes/menu.htm"; ?>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Test</h1>

            <p>Variable 1: <?php echo $var1; ?></p>
            <p>Variable 2: <?php echo $var2; ?></p>
            <p>Variable 3: <?php echo $var3; ?></p>
            <p>Variable 4: <?php echo $var4; ?></p>
            <p>Variable 5: <?php echo $var5; ?></p>
            <p>Variable 6: <?php echo $var6; ?></p>

        </div>
        <?php include_once "../includes/footer.htm" ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

your variables weren't being called by php so html took it as a literal output.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from how to use Variables in HTML parts of your code (See Answer of iamde_coder) you saved your PHP files as xxxxx.htm files. Your Webserver will not execute any such file when called but rather return it's contents, including any PHP source code.

Store your files as xxxxx.php files if they contain any PHP code and your webserver will execute them!

You might also want to read some more tutorials before diving deeper into any more application logic too.